# mysqldump doesn't restore database. why not?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.5, restore, mysqldump

**Why doesn't my restore operation work?**

I created a dumpfile for a database using:

```
mysqldump -u root -p databasename > /home/databasename_bkup.sql
```

I then opened the dumfile and confirmed that it contains `CREATE TABLE` statements for each of the tables in the database.  So I dropped the database and re-created an empty database of the same name before running the following restore command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p databasename < /home/databasename_bkup.sql
```

This restore command resulted in the following printing in the terminal:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.23, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: databasename
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.23

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2015-03-05 17:56:29
```

But then when I log into mysql to check the contents of the database, I found out that the database is empty, as follows:

```
mysql> use databasename;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

**So why is the database not being restored?  What specific syntax can I use to ensure that the database does get restored properly?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to use the mysql client to reload

```
mysql -u root -p -Ddatabasename < /home/databasename_bkup.sql
```

Another way to reload would be

```
mysql -u root -p -Ddatabasename
```

then from the MySQL prompt, do this

```
mysql> source /home/databasename_bkup.sql
```

If you would like the mysqldump to drop and recreate the database for you, create the dump like this:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --add-drop-database -B databasename > /home/databasename_bkup.sql
```

Then, running the script

```
mysql -u root -p < /home/databasename_bkup.sql
```

does the `DROP DATABASE` command for you.

Comment: oh my god I can't believe I felt for such a basic trap to use mysqldump again.

Answer (score 8):

Basically there is a basic difference between the command to take backup and restore a mysql database on linux servers

To take a backup we have to use a command `mysqldump` like this on the command prompt

```
#mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] [databasename] > [backupfilename]
```

but when you want to restore the same backup on the server, you should write a command like this

```
#mysql -u [username] -p[password] [databasename] < [backupfilename]
```

most of the time people use mysqldump command to restore the database tables thus mysql is not able to create tables or insert rows

Answer (score 6):

dont use "mysqldump" while restoring backup. Use "mysql". mysqldump is for taking backup, not for restoring.

Answer (score -4):

put "", like this
mysqldump -u root -p databasename > "c:/home/databasename_bkup.sql"